# UniswapRouter swapExactETHForTokens ValueError: VM execution error: Reverted

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I'm writing a contract for swapping on Uniswap V2 between specified tokens. Actually I should have implemented everything correctly, but when I call the swapExactETHForTokens function I always get a ValueError: Vm execution error: Reverted. Since this error is so meaningless, I don't know what to do here.

Solidity Code with Compiler Version 0.7.5:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.6;

import { SafeMath } from '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';
import { IERC20 } from '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';
import { SafeERC20 } from '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol';
import { IUniswapV2Router02 } from './../interfaces/uniswap/v2/IUniswapV2Router02.sol';

contract UniswapV2SwapExample is Withdrawable {
using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
using SafeMath for uint256;


IUniswapV2Router02 uniswapV2Router; 

constructor(address _uniswapV2Router) public {
    uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(_uniswapV2Router); 
}



function swapSingle(address tokenIn, uint amountIn, address tokenOut) internal returns (uint) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = tokenIn;
    path[1] = tokenOut;

    return swap(tokenIn, amountIn, tokenOut, path); 
} 

function swap(address tokenIn, uint amountIn, address tokenOut, address[] memory path) internal returns (uint) {
    require(IERC20(tokenIn).balanceOf(address(this)) >= amountIn, "Not enough balance to swap"); 

    require(IERC20(tokenIn).approve(address(uniswapV2Router), amountIn), 'approve failed.');

    uint balanceBefore = IERC20(tokenOut).balanceOf(address(this));

    uint[] memory amounts; 
    if (tokenIn == address(uniswapV2Router.WETH())) {

        uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokens{ value: amountIn }(0, path, address(this), block.timestamp); 
        //uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{ value: amountIn }(0, path, address(this), block.timestamp); 
    }
    else if (tokenOut == address(uniswapV2Router.WETH())) {
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETH(amountIn, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp); 
        //uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(amountIn, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp); 
    }
    else {
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp);
        //uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(amountIn, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp);
    }
    uint amountOut = IERC20(tokenOut).balanceOf(address(this)).sub(balanceBefore); 
    //uint amountOut = amounts[amounts.length-1]; 
    
    return amountOut; 
}

//Receive ETH
receive() payable external {}


function swapTest(address _assetIn, uint _amountIn, address _assetOut) public onlyOwner returns (uint) {
    return swapSingle(_assetIn, _amountIn, _assetOut); 
}



}
```

I'm Calling swapTest with brownie like:

```
weth = "0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c"
dai = "0x4f96fe3b7a6cf9725f59d353f723c1bdb64ca6aa"
amount = 100000000000000
amountOut = uniSwapExample.swapTest.call(weth, amount, dai, {"from": acct})
```

And this produces following error:

```
File "e:\python37\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 1517, in call
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
  File "e:\python37\lib\site-packages\brownie\exceptions.py", line 99, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f"{self.message}: {err_msg}") from None
ValueError: VM execution error: Reverted
```

I really need help!

Comment: In the example it seems you are sending WETH to the contract is that so? (Or it is missing the `value` parameter). If you are sending WETH then you should use `swapExactTokensForTokens` instead.

Comment: @Ismael OMG thank you! Yes I have tried to send WETH to the contract and perform the swap with it, but have not realized that WETH is interpreted differently than ETH. With swapExactTokensForTokens it works, thank you very much!